# How to merge DataFrames with slightly different merge fields

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge a set of DataFrames around a common timestamp for various assets. The data sets conatain hourly data, however the timestamp is slightly different for hour in each respective asset. So I convert the timestamp from epoch to datetime and remove seconds and minutes

```
     market_trading_pair  ohlcv_start_date  next_future_timestep_return
7073   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC        1445392800                    -0.023256
7074   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC        1445396400                     0.023810
7075   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC        1445400000                     0.000000
7076   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC        1445403600                    -0.023256
7077   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC        1445407200                     0.000000
```

Using this code:

```
TS = 'ohlcv_start_date'

df[TS] = pd.to_datetime(df[TS], unit='s').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')

print df.groupby('market_trading_pair').get_group('Poloniex_DOGE_BTC').head()[['market_trading_pair','ohlcv_start_date']]

     market_trading_pair     ohlcv_start_date  next_future_timestep_return
7073   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC  2015-10-21 02:00:00                    -0.023256
7074   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC  2015-10-21 03:00:00                     0.023810
7075   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC  2015-10-21 04:00:00                     0.000000
7076   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC  2015-10-21 05:00:00                    -0.023256
7077   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC  2015-10-21 06:00:00                     0.000000
```

Making a new dataFrame with required data:

```
timestamp   DOGE
7073    2015-10-21 02:00:00 -0.023256
7074    2015-10-21 03:00:00 0.023810
7075    2015-10-21 04:00:00 0.000000
7076    2015-10-21 05:00:00 -0.023256
7077    2015-10-21 06:00:00 0.000000
```

I then create a 'skeleton' timeframe DataFrame that I will be able to merge all data frames to and merge a just one frame to test.

```
timeframe = pd.date_range(start=min_time, end=max_time, freq='H')
test = DataFrame(timeframe, columns=['timestamp']) 


timestamp
0   2015-10-21 02:00:00
1   2015-10-21 03:00:00
2   2015-10-21 04:00:00
3   2015-10-21 05:00:00
4   2015-10-21 06:00:00

test = pd.merge(left=test, right=to_merge, left_on='timestamp',right_on='timestamp',how='left')

    timestamp   DOGE
0   2015-10-21 02:00:00 NaN
1   2015-10-21 03:00:00 NaN
2   2015-10-21 04:00:00 NaN
3   2015-10-21 05:00:00 NaN
```

And the result is nan fields I think it maybe due to a formatting error ? However I compared the timestamp strings and they came out 'True'

Comment: I think problem is with dtypes - column `DOGE` in `to_merge` is string and next column is `datetime` - so it cannot merge. Can you check `print to_merge.dtypes` and `print test.dtypes` ?

Comment: Hazar ! I think you got it sir

`timestamp     object
DOGE         float64
dtype: object`

`timestamp    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object`

How would i convert one of the types to the other types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `dtypes` - cannot merge column type `string` with type `datetime`, because then output is `NaN`:

```
print df
               timestamp      DOGE
7073 2015-10-21 02:00:00 -0.023256
7074 2015-10-21 03:00:00  0.023810
7075 2015-10-21 04:00:00  0.000000
7076 2015-10-21 05:00:00 -0.023256
7077 2015-10-21 06:00:00  0.000000
print df.dtypes
timestamp    datetime64[ns]
DOGE                float64
dtype: object
```

```
min_time = df['timestamp'].min()
max_time = df['timestamp'].max()


df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
print df
                timestamp      DOGE
7073  2015-10-21 02:00:00 -0.023256
7074  2015-10-21 03:00:00  0.023810
7075  2015-10-21 04:00:00  0.000000
7076  2015-10-21 05:00:00 -0.023256
7077  2015-10-21 06:00:00  0.000000
print df.dtypes
timestamp     object  **************
DOGE         float64
dtype: object

timeframe = pd.date_range(start=min_time, end=max_time, freq='H')
test = pd.DataFrame(timeframe, columns=['timestamp']) 
print test
            timestamp
0 2015-10-21 02:00:00
1 2015-10-21 03:00:00
2 2015-10-21 04:00:00
3 2015-10-21 05:00:00
4 2015-10-21 06:00:00

print test.dtypes
timestamp    datetime64[ns] ****************
dtype: object
```

```
print pd.merge(left=test, right=df, on='timestamp', how='left')
            timestamp  DOGE
0 2015-10-21 02:00:00   NaN
1 2015-10-21 03:00:00   NaN
2 2015-10-21 04:00:00   NaN
3 2015-10-21 05:00:00   NaN
4 2015-10-21 06:00:00   NaN
```

**Solution**

Remove converting column of type `datetime` to `string`:

Change:

```
df[TS] = pd.to_datetime(df[TS], unit='s').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

to:

```
df[TS] = pd.to_datetime(df[TS], unit='s')
```

It means (I comment converting to `string`):

```
print df.dtypes
timestamp    datetime64[ns] ***********
DOGE                float64
dtype: object

min_time = df['timestamp'].min()
max_time = df['timestamp'].max()


#df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
#print df
#print df.dtypes


timeframe = pd.date_range(start=min_time, end=max_time, freq='H')
test = pd.DataFrame(timeframe, columns=['timestamp']) 
print test.dtypes
timestamp    datetime64[ns]   ***********
dtype: object

print pd.merge(left=test, right=df, on='timestamp', how='left')
            timestamp      DOGE
0 2015-10-21 02:00:00 -0.023256
1 2015-10-21 03:00:00  0.023810
2 2015-10-21 04:00:00  0.000000
3 2015-10-21 05:00:00 -0.023256
4 2015-10-21 06:00:00  0.000000
```